# EhCache 3.10.8 is not evicting cached entries in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I am using EhCache 3.10.8 and SpringBoot 2.4.0. I have the following Spring bean-based configuration with a TTL of 30 seconds. I am calling a method using Cacheable annotation to populate the entries in the cache. But the entries are not getting evicted even after ~5 minutes.
Is this bean definition correct? What can I do to make sure that the cache would be evicted after the configured TTL? 
**build.gradle**

```
//Caching
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.7.0'
implementation 'javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.1'
implementation 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.8'
```

**CacheConfig**

```
package com.example.application.config;

import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ExpiryPolicyBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Configuration;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider;
import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();

        CacheConfigurationBuilder<String, Boolean> configuration =
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                    String.class,
                    Boolean.class,
                    ResourcePoolsBuilder
                        .newResourcePoolsBuilder().offheap(5, MemoryUnit.MB))
              .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));

        javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<String, Boolean> cacheConfiguration =
            Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(configuration);

        cacheManager.createCache("isUrlVerified", cacheConfiguration);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

**Cacheable usage**

```
@Cacheable(value = "isUrlVerified", key = "#url")
public Boolean verifyUrl(String url) {
    //Code to call another service to check if URL is valid
}
```

Comment: Implement the `CacheConfigurer` interface in your configuration and return your cache manager from the `cacheManager` method.